# What might cause scheduled Rails Active Jobs to disappear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I have a suspicion that some our active jobs are disappearing but I don't know why. Below is one I have found the evidence for it's disappearance, but not the reason why.

Our site makes use of an external cloud printing service. We kick the jobs off and then check their status. Having successfully created the remote cloud print, we create an active job to check the status immediately. If it's finished (successfully or otherwise), it's marked as such. If not then the check status job creates another one, with a slight delay. The delay increases each time.

One a status check today, the logs show that the wait reached 128 seconds. But the next status check did not occur, and there are no errors in the log either.

We use active job backed by delayed job. The code for the status check job is below. It can't see any flaw in the logic which would not result in either correctly collected status check or another attempt with a wait.

```
class CheckCloudPrintStatusJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(cloud_print, count = 0)
    cloud_print.update_status

    unless cloud_print.finished?
      count += 1
      wait = 2**(count-1)

      if count > 15
        cloud_print.mark_as_failed

        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Cloud printing ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        puts "Cloud print ##{cloud_print.id} failed"
        puts "Finally waited #{wait} seconds and then cancelled."
        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
      else
        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Cloud printing ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        puts "Checking status of cloud print ##{cloud_print.id}"
        puts "Waiting #{wait} seconds and then retrying."
        puts "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"

        CheckCloudPrintStatusJob.set(wait: wait.seconds).perform_later(cloud_print, count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what happens when `update_status` raises an error? can you also share code in `update_status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, there is no flaw in the stated logic that would result in either correctly collected status check or another attempt with a wait.

I've verified that your job code behaves successfully beyond a 128-second wait with the following setup:

- `rails new` project
- `delayed_job_active_record` added to the `Gemfile` (running `bundle install`)
- `rails generate delayed_job:active_record` and `rake db:migrate` to install gems and create the Delayed Job DB table
- `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` in `config/application.rb`
- a basic `CloudPrint < ApplicationRecord` model with `update_status`, `finished?` and `mark_as_failed` methods in `app/models/cloud_print.rb`
- the provided code in `app/jobs/check_cloud_print_status_job.rb`
- Enqueuing a job by running `CheckCloudPrintStatusJob.perform_later(CloudPrint.create)` via the Rails Console (`bin/rails c`)

Since the above sequence behaved correctly without any issue, you need to expand your search by providing a more [complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually reproduces the problem. Either upload your entire Rails project into a GitHub repo once you've been able to reproduce your issue consistently, or investigate other aspects of your environment and project configuration. Here are some possibilities:

- There could be logic in your model class that could possibly raise any exceptions;
- The worker-processing daemon could have been aborted or killed;
- The job queue could have been cleared (e.g., via `rake jobs:clear`)
- Another process could have modified and/or deleted the model object being processed;
- `finished?` could have returned `true` after `update_status` was invoked, causing the final status check to not have been printed even though the processing finished successfully.

N.B. - Delayed Job supports retrying failed jobs with a delay of `5 seconds + N ** 4`, where `N` is the number of attempts, there's no need to re-implement this logic yourself. Just `raise` an exception if `cloud_print.finished?` is false, and you shouldn't need any other custom delay code:

```
class CheckCloudPrintStatusJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(cloud_print)
    raise 'Not ready' unless cloud_print.finished?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive responsive. While your answer didn't directly solve the problem for us, it was helpful in making us think about where else the problem might lie. Bizarrely, the solution seems to have been (apart from to add a lot of extra safety) to switch from dj to sidekiq. Clearly that shouldn't make a difference, but apparently it does.

Answer (score 0):

As it implies from the job code, the argument `cloud_print` is an instance of some Ruby class (seems ActiveRecord::Base). That is not a good idea in general to have complicated objects as arguments for background job because these arguments have to be serialized into string, json or yaml. DelayedJob uses YAML-serialized objects and sometimes it might be not possible to restore a model instance. For example, if delayed job runs as callback `before_create` - model object has not been saved and could not be restored then. More information could be found here https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#jobs-are-silently-removed-from-the-database

Comment: Since Rails 5 (at least), ActiveJob use GlobalId when passing ActiveModel

as described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid 

That means that we can pass a ActiceRecord object, and it will store the Class + Id and not serialised the attributes of the object.

We still have to take care of the after_create issue with the transactions